# Postgresql 8.2 DEBUG: Error 2769: Custom Action GetAvailableLocales did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to install PostgreSQL 8.2 on Windows XP, but it fails with the "error 2769:  Custom Action GetAvailableLocales did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs".
Thanks, see below the logs

```
=== Verbose logging started: 06/11/2015  10:50:26  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 
3.01.4000.4039  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe === MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:26:218]: Resetting cached policy values MSI (c)
(E4:84) [10:50:26:218]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0 MSI (c)
(E4:84) [10:50:26:218]: ******* RunEngine:
            ******* Product: C:\PostGreSql 8.2.6-1\postgresql-8.2-int.msi
            ******* Action: 
            ******* CommandLine: ********** MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:26:218]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0 MSI
 (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:656]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying
 package --> 'C:\PostGreSql 8.2.6-1\postgresql-8.2-int.msi' against
 software restriction policy MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:656]: Note: 1:
 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84)
 [10:50:27:656]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\PostGreSql
 8.2.6-1\postgresql-8.2-int.msi is not digitally signed MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:656]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\PostGreSql
 8.2.6-1\postgresql-8.2-int.msi is permitted to run because the user token authorizes execution (marked SANDBOX_INERT). MSI (c) (E4:84)
[10:50:27:671]: Cloaking enabled. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]:
 Attempting to enable all disabled priveleges before calling Install on
 Server MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]: End dialog not enabled MSI (c)
 (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]: Original package ==> C:\PostGreSql
 8.2.6-1\postgresql-8.2-int.msi MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]: Package we're running from ==> C:\DOCUME~1\ratp\LOCALS~1\Temp\473dda.msi MSI
 (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database
 entry with ProductCode '{1F701DBD-1660-4108-B10A-FB435EA63BF0}'. MSI
 (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found
 in database. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:671]: MSCOREE not loaded
 loading copy from system32 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine
policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Looking for storage transform: lang_fr MSI (c) (E4:84)

[10:50:27:687]: Validating transform 'lang_fr' with validation bits 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Transform 'lang_fr' is valid. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Tables 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Columns 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: File 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: TRANSFORM: 'PatchPackage' table is missing or empty.  No pre-transform fixup necessary. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: TRANSFORM: Applying regular transform to database. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Tables 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Columns 3:
-2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TextStyle 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdvtExecuteSequence 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Condition 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: File 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CheckBox 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallExecuteSequence 3:
-2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SelfReg 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ControlEvent 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ComboBox 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Binary 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminUISequence 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: InstallUISequence 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Component 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ServiceControl 3:
-2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CustomAction 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ListBox 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Environment 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: EventMapping 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ControlCondition 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3:
-2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ReserveCost 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: FeatureComponents 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminExecuteSequence 3:
-2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _Validation 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_PatchCache 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineData 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineFile 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: #_BaselineCost 3:
-2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: _MsiPatchTransformView 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{1F701DBD-1660-4108-B10A-FB435EA63BF0}'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Transforms are not secure. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Transforming table Property.

MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Transforming table Control.

MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Command Line: TRANSFORMS=:lang_fr INTERNALLAUNCH=1 CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\WINDOWS\system32 CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=2788  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{695EEF9B-1481-4A70-999E-8F2282BEE022}'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TRANSFORMS property. Its value is ':lang_fr'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           '' MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{1F701DBD-1660-4108-B10A-FB435EA63BF0}' MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{1F701DBD-1660-4108-B10A-FB435EA63BF0}' MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu' MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Adding new sources is allowed. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Package name extracted from package path: 'postgresql-8.2-int.msi' MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Package to be registered: 'postgresql-8.2-int.msi' MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2729  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Running product '{1F701DBD-1660-4108-B10A-FB435EA63BF0}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INTERNALLAUNCH property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '2788'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: TRANSFORMS property is now: :lang_fr MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '110'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Application Data MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Favoris MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Voisinage réseau MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Mes documents MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Voisinage d'impression MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Recent MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\SendTo MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Modèles MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Local Settings\Application Data MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Mes documents\Mes images MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Outils d'administration MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Démarrage MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Démarrer\Programmes MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Démarrer MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Bureau MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Outils d'administration MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Démarrage MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Menu Démarrer\Programmes MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Menu Démarrer MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\ratp\Bureau MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Modèles MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:687]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'carteblanche'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'carteblanche'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\DOCUME~1\ratp\LOCALS~1\Temp\473dda.msi'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\PostGreSql 8.2.6-1\postgresql-8.2-int.msi'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\PostGreSql 8.2.6-1\'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\PostGreSql 8.2.6-1\'. MSI (c) (E4:E8) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '3.01'. MSI (c) (E4:E8) [10:50:27:703]: Transforming table UIText.

MSI (c) (E4:E8) [10:50:27:703]: Transforming table Dialog.

MSI (c) (E4:E8) [10:50:27:703]: Transforming table Dialog.

=== Début de l'écriture dans le journal : 06/11/2015  10:50:27 === MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Doing action: INSTALL MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Transforming table ActionText.

Action 10:50:27 : INSTALL.  Début de l'action 10:50:27 : INSTALL. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Running UISequence MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Doing action: AppSearch Action 10:50:27 : AppSearch. Recherche des applications déjà installées Début de l'action 10:50:27 : AppSearch. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: AppSearch  MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: AppSearch 4: SELECT `Property`, `Signature_` FROM `AppSearch`  Fin de l'action 10:50:27 : AppSearch. Valeur renvoyée : 0. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Doing action: LaunchConditions Action 10:50:27 : LaunchConditions. Évaluation des conditions de lancement Début de l'action 10:50:27 : LaunchConditions. Fin de l'action 10:50:27 : LaunchConditions. Valeur renvoyée : 1. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:703]: Doing action: GetAvailableLocales Action 10:50:27 : GetAvailableLocales.  Début de l'action 10:50:27 : GetAvailableLocales. MSI (c) (E4:10) [10:50:27:718]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\ratp\LOCALS~1\Temp\MSI35.tmp, Entrypoint: GetAvailableLocales@4 MSI (c) (E4:CC) [10:50:27:718]: Cloaking enabled. MSI (c) (E4:CC) [10:50:27:718]: Attempting to enable all disabled priveleges before calling Install on Server MSI (c) (E4:CC) [10:50:27:718]: Connected to service for CA interface. MSI (c) (E4!00) [10:50:27:765]: Note: 1: 2259 2:  3:  4:   MSI (c) (E4:10) [10:50:27:796]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (3) of type 790540 for thread 2816 MSI (c) (E4:10) [10:50:27:796]: Note: 1: 2769 2: GetAvailableLocales 3: 1  MSI (c) (E4:10) [10:50:27:796]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error  MSI (c) (E4:10) [10:50:27:796]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2769  DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action GetAvailableLocales did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs. Windows Installer a rencontré une erreur inattendue lors de l'installation de ce package. Il s'agit peut-être d'un problème lié au package. Le code d'erreur est 2769. Les arguments sont : GetAvailableLocales, 1,  Fin de l'action 10:50:27 : GetAvailableLocales. Valeur renvoyée : 1. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:796]: Doing action: CheckAvailableDLLs Action 10:50:27 : CheckAvailableDLLs.  Début de l'action 10:50:27 : CheckAvailableDLLs. MSI (c) (E4:C0) [10:50:27:796]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\ratp\LOCALS~1\Temp\MSI36.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckAvailableDLLs@4 MSI (c) (E4!E0) [10:50:27:812]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying SERVICEDOMAIN property. Its current value is '.'. Its new value: 'BORNEESSAIVISU'. Fin de l'action 10:50:27 : CheckAvailableDLLs. Valeur renvoyée : 1. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:812]: Skipping action: DisableInitdb (condition is false) MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:812]: Doing action: ValidateProductID Action 10:50:27 : ValidateProductID.  Début de l'action 10:50:27 : ValidateProductID. Fin de l'action 10:50:27 : ValidateProductID. Valeur renvoyée : 1. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:812]: Doing action: CostInitialize Action 10:50:27 : CostInitialize. Calcul de l'espace requis Début de l'action 10:50:27 : CostInitialize. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:812]: Machine policy value 'MaxPatchCacheSize' is 10 MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:828]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ROOTDRIVE property. Its value is 'C:\'. MSI (c) (E4:84) [10:50:27:828]: Transforming table Directory.
```

Comment: Installing Postgres **8.2** in 2015? Why? 8.2. has been de-supported for 4 years now. Why don't you install a current and supported version? (And the name is spelled PostgreSQL, not PostGreSql)

Comment: What @a_horse_with_no_name says, plus you are trying to install version 8.2.6, the latest 8.2.x release is 8.2.23.